# Multiple calculations in jQuery with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do 2-3 calculations at once with jQuery. I found a link to a fiddle that did one calculation and I edited it to what I thought I needed to make it all work, but I can only get the one-off calculation to work.

Basically, I'm calculating the overall width and height of tires based on the metric sizes.

Example: 265/70R17
The width is calculated by dividing the 3-digit width (265) by 25.4 = 10.43

The height is calculated by taking the width in inches, multiplying by the ratio (70), then doubling that number before adding the size of the rim (17).  So, ((10.43 * .7) * 2) + 17 = 31.60

Here's the link to the fiddle that I've been trying to make work.
http://jsfiddle.net/fY57T/

```
$('#rim').change(function(ev){
    var twidth = $('#width').val() / 25.4;
    var step1height = $('#ratio').val() * twidth;
    var step2height = step1height * 2; 
    var theight = step2height + $('#rim').val(); 
  $('#theight').html((theight).toFixed(2));
  $('#twidth').html((twidth).toFixed(2));
});
```

Thanks in advance for any input anyone has.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with addition of `step2height` and `rim` id value, its considered as strings, not number. you need to use `parseInt()` to convert them to numbers

```
var theight = step2height + $('#rim').val();
```

Should be changed to

```
var theight = parseInt(step2height) + parseInt($('#rim').val());
```

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fY57T/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for vote up. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I Feel I'm headed in the right direction.  However, my last remaining issue is that only the width displays correctly (correct to the hundredths place).  The height is rounding, so instead of displaying 31.62, it is showing up as 31.00.  Here's my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cv2cj/

Comment: ok as per requirement, you need to use parseFloat. Here is fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/Cv2cj/1/